# Verificar se ip já está registrado no banco de dados

Tags: php, mysql

O código abaixa verifica se o ip do usuário já está registrado no banco de dados, mas ele continua enviando a informação que o ip está livre, mesmo já estando registrado no banco de dados.

```
   $ip = $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"];

    $query = mysql_query("SELECT ip FROM emails WHERE ip = '$ip'");
    $countUser = mysql_num_rows($query);

    if($countUser > 0){
      while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
        echo "IP já registrado";
      }
    } else {
      echo "IP livre";
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não sei qual a versão do seu PHP, mas na versão que uso (versão 7) esse código seu não funciona.

Se consultar o manual, terá

> Aviso
>   Esta extensão está obsoleta desde o PHP 5.5.0 e foi removida no PHP 7.0.0. Utilize MySQLi ou PDO_MySQL alternativamente.

No PHP 7, funciona assim:

```
$con = mysqli_connect("host","user","pass","dbname");

if(!$con) {
    echo "Erro: falha ao se conectar com o banco <br>";
    echo "Errno: " . mysqli_connect_errno() . PHP_EOL;
}

$ip = $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"];
$query = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT `ip` FROM `emails` WHERE `ip` = '$ip'");
$countUser = mysqli_num_rows($query);

if($countUser > 0){
  while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
    echo "IP já registrado";
  }
} else {
  echo "IP livre";
}

mysqli_close($con);
```